# Smallest way to expand a list by n

Tags: python, list

i want to expand a list

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

by *n*

e.g. for n = 2:

```
[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]
```

I'm searching for the smallest possible way to achieve this without any additional librarys.
Its easy to do a loop and append each item n times to a new list... but is there a other way?

Comment: @jamylak ``itertools`` is in the standard library, so not using it would be silly.

Comment: Also, how do you want this to act - in this case, it's immutable objects, but how should it act on mutable objects?

Comment: by smallest did you mean the length/beauty of code or the execution time?

Comment: @Schinken ok, I posted solution which seems to have the smallest length among the others

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> [it for it in l for _ in range(2)]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

Comment: There is a warning here for mutable objects. If you let l equal ``[1, 2, [3]]`` then follow your method, then do ``test2[4].append(4)`` you will get ``[1, 1, 2, 2, [3, 4], [3, 4]]``. Obviously, this won't be a problem in most cases, but worth noting.

Comment: It will work in Python 2.x and 3.x - the issue is that you simply have two references to the same item, so when you update either of them, the other will update too.

Answer (score 5):

[`itertools` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) to the rescue:

```
expanded = list(chain(*izip(*tee(l, n))))
```

Comment: Whoa. As much as I like `itertools`, this is giving me a headache :)

Comment: What has this got to do with `itertools`?

Comment: @TimPietzcker I found this easier to read than hamstergene's answer.

Comment: @jamylak where do you think `izip`, `tee`, and `chain` come from?

Comment: Oh weird sorry he edited the answer and i was looking at the old one hahahaha.

Comment: expanded = list(chain(*izip(*tee(l, n))))

Comment: @Marcin It lets you do quick edits without showing them. I saw the old version too.

Comment: @jamylak I don't see the difference from the current version.

Comment: Argh, sorry copied the wrong text, when i went back in the web browser i think it must have loaded the new page but nevertheless there was an old version that didn't use itertools.

Answer (score 4):

I made note of this in comments, but it's easier to explain in an answer so I can give full code examples. Please note this is more of a companion answer to others, rather than a full one in it's own right. It is simply a modification for a specific case.

If you need to do this with mutable objects, you hit a snag using the other methods presented here:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,[4]]
>>> test = [it for it in l for _ in range(2)]
>>> test
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, [4], [4]]
>>> test[6].append(5)
>>> test
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, [4, 5], [4, 5]]
```

As such, you need to use [`copy.deepcopy()`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) if you want to avoid this behaviour.

```
>>> import copy
>>> l = [1,2,3,[4]]
>>> test = [copy.deepcopy(it) for it in l for _ in range(2)]
>>> test
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, [4], [4]]
>>> test[6].append(5)
>>> test
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, [4, 5], [4]]
```

Naturally, this is only necesary for mutable objects in a list, and only if you expect them to change after creating your new list.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from itertools import chain, tee
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> n = 2
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(zip(*tee(x, n))))
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

Comment: Why did you replicate another answer?

Comment: I only saw his older version like i said in the comments, I thought of this myself. Delete it if you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
sum([[x]*2 for x in l],[])
```

where `l` is your list

Comment: So in order to repeat the elements three times, I have to write `sum([[x,x,x] for x in l],[])`? This seems less convenient.

Comment: Or it can be changed to: `sum([[x]*3 for x in l],[])`

Comment: @FelixKling: see jamylak's comment for what I left implicit in my answer. Though I guess since the OP wanted `n` and not 2, I think I will change that from `[x,x]`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the author of the question answers in the comment that by "the smallest possible way" he means the smallest length of the code, I dare to post the following solution:

```
>>> sorted([1,2,3,4]*2)
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

It's length is 19.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import repeat, chain
>>> seq = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(x, 2) for x in seq))
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> seq = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(zip(*[seq]*2)))
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(zip(*[seq]*6)))
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```